Arduino UNO: Everything is working except light censor
This is a simple Arduino UNO project that can turn on and off the LED light with push button or light censor.
The push button is perfectly working it turns on and off the LED light without any problem. The light censor is working too, I debugged it and it can detect light. My problem is even though the light level (>400) is more than the threshold (400), it still does not turn the LED on or off like no effect. (with light 500-700).
Here is my Arduino diagram. (The green line is light censor)  Arduino Diagram
And Here is my code.


int ledPin = 13;        // LED connected to digital pin 13
int lightSensorPin = A0;  // Photoresistor connected to analog pin A0
int btnPin = 2;         // Button connected to digital pin 2
int threshold = 400;    // Light level threshold (adjust based on your sensor and environment)

int state = LOW;        // Current state of the LED

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);       // Set the LED pin as an output
  pinMode(btnPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // Set the button pin as input with an internal pull-up resistor
  Serial.begin(9600);            // Initialize serial communication for debugging
}

void loop() {
  int lightLevel = analogRead(lightSensorPin);  // Read the light sensor value
  int buttonState = digitalRead(btnPin);        // Read the button state

  // Debugging: Print the light sensor value and button state
  Serial.print("Light Level: ");
  Serial.print(lightLevel);
  Serial.print(" | Button State: ");
  Serial.println(buttonState);

  // Toggle LED state when button is pressed
  if (buttonState == LOW) {  // Button pressed (active LOW)
    delay(50);  // Debounce delay
    if (digitalRead(btnPin) == LOW) {  // Confirm button is still pressed
      state = !state;  // Toggle the state
      digitalWrite(ledPin, state);  // Update the LED
      while (digitalRead(btnPin) == LOW) {
        // Wait for button release to avoid multiple toggles
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    // Control LED based on light sensor only if the button is not pressed
    if (lightLevel < threshold) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);   // Turn on the LED if light level is below the threshold
    } else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // Turn off the LED if light level is above the threshold
    }
  }

  delay(100);  // Small delay to smooth the sensor readings
}




On your 50 ms debounce check -- I believe Arduino automatically handles debounce on inputs. Either via hardware or software. You may be able to remove your debounce check entirely.

What light level values are you getting? Are you getting values both above and below 400?

digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);   // Turn on the LED. I guess HIGH turns the LED on on your Uno

@JohnFilleau - There are some third party libraries that do debouncing, but the Arduino itself doesn't do anything about bounce.

What range of readings do you get from Serial.print(lightLevel); when the light is on and when it is off?

I get 500-700 light level with light, and without light is 20-100. The threshold is 400.

The comments on the digitalWrites near the bottom of the code sample appear to say the opposite of what the code actually does.  With the built-in LED on pin 13, writing HIGH turns the LED on, not off.  The state variable tracks the LED's state only in terms of the button presses.  If the LED is on because of the light level, and you press the button, it might turn off the LED or it might remain on.  Maybe that's your intent.  If not, that could be confusing things.

I have run your code on an Arduino Uno with the button connected as you have, and with a potentiometer in place of the LDR. As I turn the potentiometer taking the analogue reading past the 400 value, the LED switches accordingly. So your code works.
In order to get a better idea of what is going on, you could edit your code so that you get an analogue reading to the serial port closer to where you use the value. So try this:
int ledPin = 13;        // LED connected to digital pin 13
int lightSensorPin = A0;  // Photoresistor connected to analog pin A0
int btnPin = 2;         // Button connected to digital pin 2
int threshold = 400;    // Light level threshold (adjust based on your sensor and environment)

int state = LOW;        // Current state of the LED

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);       // Set the LED pin as an output
  pinMode(btnPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // Set the button pin as input with an internal pull-up resistor
  Serial.begin(9600);            // Initialize serial communication for debugging
}

void loop() {
  int lightLevel = analogRead(lightSensorPin);  // Read the light sensor value
  int buttonState = digitalRead(btnPin);        // Read the button state
/*
  // Debugging: Print the light sensor value and button state
  Serial.print("Light Level: ");
  Serial.print(lightLevel);
  Serial.print(" | Button State: ");
  Serial.println(buttonState);
*/
  // Toggle LED state when button is pressed
  if (buttonState == LOW) {  // Button pressed (active LOW)
    delay(50);  // Debounce delay
    if (digitalRead(btnPin) == LOW) {  // Confirm button is still pressed
      state = !state;  // Toggle the state
      digitalWrite(ledPin, state);  // Update the LED
      while (digitalRead(btnPin) == LOW) {
        // Wait for button release to avoid multiple toggles
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    lightLevel = analogRead(lightSensorPin);
    Serial.print("Light Level: ");
    Serial.println(lightLevel);  //note I am using println here
    
    // Control LED based on light sensor only if the button is not pressed
    if (lightLevel < threshold) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);   // Turn on the LED if light level is below the threshold
    } else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // Turn off the LED if light level is above the threshold
    }
  }

  delay(100);  // Small delay to smooth the sensor readings
}

I have also commented out the other code sending to the serial port to clarify what is going on.
As you change the light level you should see the value transition the 400 level, as reported via the serial monitor. At that point you should see the LED change state.
If you see the serial readout then there is no way that the LED can fail to change state. If you don't see the serial readount, it must be that the (buttonState == LOW) condition is preventing the code from reaching the LDR part.

I appreciate your help. I tried your code, and it's still the same for me. I'm a beginner, so maybe I'm missing something. I can share a video of my work maybe it can help. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EwUkaAj2Y_OXC7BisrWPR3L-C60a99Gb/view?usp=sharing In the video it shows that the light level is low, and as I put my camera with my flash, it doesn't affect the led light. I clicked the button, so I would see in my serial monitor how much light level there was, and it's 600+. So, I don't know what's wrong.

If you run my code, it will continuously print the light level to the serial monitor at the point where you are checking its value and controlling the LED. Now bring the light up to the LDR and you should see the printed light level change and cross the 400 threshold. At that point the LED will change. But you must run my version of your code. Please do that, and tell me what happens as you bring the light closer to the LDR.

I did run your code on the video I sent, and it does not continuously print for me. I just tried today to remove the button code, and it do work. So for me, the button code is the problem. And I'm using your code.

As you say, the button code is preventing the LDR code from running. This is odd because I ran your code on the same setup, and did not have that problem. But anyway if you recode it to remove the button check you can at least get the LDR code to work. If you think that the problem is resolved, please accept my answer so that others are aware.

Can I have a favor? can I have a video of it working by pointing light and with button. I need it for my project. and i also need a pic of components used. just like this: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nzNAHYwi3ZNA9KgW7DDg689f6VOymC70?usp=drive_link thanks.

Sorry I have already disconnected it, and anyway I was using a pot in place of the LDR.
